# What are advantages of hide glue and when should I use it?

Tags: glue

The majority of all my work has used conventional wood glues with an occasional application of gorilla glue for certain exterior situations.  I confess that I know little about hide glue and its application. Can anyone shed some light on how and when to best apply it?

Answer (score 5):

My only experience is with liquid hide glue.  It is also available as a solid that needs "assembled" before use.  I believe it's biggest benefit is it reversible.  You can read more about it here: http://www.popularwoodworking.com/woodworking-blogs/chris-schwarz-blog/best-wood-gluefranklin-liquid-hide-glue

Comment: that sounds right - also - I think there is a charm to it and thats hard to quantify